# what is the rsconnect command to deploy a learnr site?

Tags: r, learnr, rsconnect

I have a simple one-page `learnr` site containing several quizzes. It works fine and deploys fine when I press the Deploy ("Publish the application") button in rstudio IDE. I would like to be able to do this programmatically. I have tried commands like

```
rsconnect::deployApp(account="accountname",forceUpdate = T,lint=F,appPrimaryDoc = "quizzes/quizzes.Rmd")
```

which produce the same messages as pressing the button but the learnr site is not deployed correctly (it won't start, displaying the Please Wait message).

I can't find the correct command to deploy a learnr site. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Use `rsconnect::deployDoc` instead (https://johannestitz.com/post/2022-04-14-how-to-deploy-learnr-tutorials-to-shinyapps-io-with-rsconnect/)

Comment: rsconnect::deployDoc(doc = "mydoc.Rmd", account="myaccount")